# How does the loot drop in multiplayer, per person or free for all?

Tags: torchlight-2

In Torchlight 2, how does the loot drop in multiplayer games?  Does it drop assigned to individual characters? Or is it just a first come first served kind of deal?

I ask because I play games with a few guys that are loot hoarders to the point that it almost ruins games (the old, "hey there is a chest over there, I am going to stop killing this monster and go get it while the monster slaughter you!")

The dropping of loot will really determine if this game becomes one I play solo, or we play as a group.

Comment: They have been assuring since day 1 that loot is instanced, meaning per person. But I'd like to hear it from someone who has had a chance to play * shakes fist at 10 am release *

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Loot drops are per-person.  I just played a LAN game for a few minutes and all the dropped equipment and gold was exclusive to me, unseeable and untouchable by other players in the session.

Comment: Good to hear! It's too bad the other people can't see the loot and just not pick it up though.  It is a fun to taunt the item hoarders with seeing all the sweet loot I got that they didn't!