# How things are shared when playing LAN?

Tags: torchlight-2

I've just started playing Torchlight 2, and I'm playing over a LAN with a friend (we are about level 10 now). We are doing the same quests together and I'm wondering how the experience, gold and loot are split between the players.

Does each player earn the same amount of experience, apart of the number of mobs that each one kills? Do the monsters get stronger when there is more than one player in the world? Do we need to be close to each other to share experience? How the loot system work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the loot drop in multiplayer, per person or free for all?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85134/how-does-the-loot-drop-in-multiplayer-per-person-or-free-for-all)

Comment: @SaintWacko That only covers one part of the question.

Comment: That's another thing. Generally you should only ask one question per question. You have five here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Experience is shared, if you're close enough to each other.

Mobs are scaled up the more players are in an area.

For these effects to happen you need to be roughly on the same screen as the other player(s)<sup>1</sup>.

Loot is instanced for each player (i.e. you see separate loot), though of course you can trade.

See [Torchlight Wiki: Multiplayer features](http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Multiplayer_features) and [Torchlight Wiki: Difficulty](http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Difficulty_%28T2%29).

<sup>1</sup>[Runic Forums: Difficulty in multiplayer?](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=34572#p315609)

Comment: Instanced loot is one of the best things about the multiplayer! No treading on each others' toes, especially with >2 players. Just pick up EVERYTHING. Then sell it. Thanks, Mr Slinkyboots the ferret!

Comment: An anonymous user suggested an edit that implied that monsters scale but players don't. Does any source support that?

Comment: that sounds right - [this wiki page](http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Difficulty_(T2)) supports that

Comment: Unfortunate that two pages on the same wiki contradict each other then, but it does seem that mob scaling is correct over player scaling.

Comment: Where is there a contradiction? If you're interpreting the bit where it says "players do less damage to monsters" as player scaling, well, it doesn't matter whether monsters _or_ players are scaled, does it? End result is the same.