# Does multiplayer or difficulty affect loot quality or quantity?

Tags: torchlight-2

Does multiplayer or difficulty affect the quality or quantity of loot that drops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loot is instanced. [Each player sees only their own loot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/85134/27134), so the general loot quantity is unaffected by playing multiplayer, regardless of how many players are playing.

Neither the number of players you have in your party or the difficulty level effects loot quality. In order to get better drops you want to be stacking magic find, and as the loot is all instanced, this will affect the loot that drops for *you*, rather than being split out across your party like in other games.

Comment: As long as you have enough magic find you can play whatever you want and get the same loot as with 4 players on elite? so why should you play elite or multiplayer anyway (aside from the challenge)

Comment: ***For*** the challenge - look at it another way, why is it fair that a less skilled player gets less access to loot, thus reducing their enjoyment in the game and/or preventing them from getting legendary items? It's not fun for a skilled player to play on a low difficulty, it's not fun for a less-skilled player to die all the time on a higher difficulty.

Comment: Cause its the System already: if you arent skilled enough you are unable to beat the game thus you'll never get better loot. But anyway, thanks for the help :)